# Place google +1 button on all pages to recommend homepage

Tags: google-plus-one

I have seen sites with a fixed position box at the corner of every page containing a google +1 button and they encourage users to recommend the website as a whole by clicking the button.

**This way every +1 button on every page will recommend the homepage! and not the page user is viewing.**

Is this possible? and if Possible is leagal(based on google policy)? and if leagal, doese this practice improves the SEO of the site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unclear; seems to be about legal implications of G+ buttons and SEO; and has nothing whatsoever to do with code

Comment: I need to know what can I code before I code them! If this is beyond the scope of SO then close this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a CSS like this (adjust the width/height, top,left as you see fit):

```
#googleplus {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

and use it like this (on every page):

```
<div id="googleplus"><!-- google +1 code here --></div>
```

Now, this div will be on top of everything on your page and should remain there, as you scroll up/down.

As for the legality, you should check Google +1 [policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy)

As for the merits regarding doing this to improve your SEO - it depends on your user base no? If they see the button on every page and they like your site, they are more more likely to click it and share it. (because the button is there, always).

Comment: Is that true that you recommend the current page by clicking the +1? then how come there is only one +1 button on all site ? ( the number of +1 is same for all subpages means you see 2.3k on all pages)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/ (you can specify the target url using `data-href`)